# Testing svelte components with import.meta.env

Tags: jestjs, babeljs, svelte, vite

I'm struggeling now for a couple of days to get my testsetup running. Rough outline: Vite, Svelte (with ts), Jest.

I'm using import.meta.env.SOMENAME for my environment vars although this works fine for development as soon as a component uses import.meta.env the test will fail with:

> SyntaxError: Cannot use 'import.meta' outside a module

I've tried different transformers, babel-plugins and configs but never succeeded...

My jest config:

```js
"jest": {
    "globals": {
      "ts-jest": {
        "isolatedModules": true
      }
    },
    "verbose": true,
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.svelte$": [
        "svelte-jester",
        {
          "preprocess": true
        }
      ],
      "^.+\\.ts$": "ts-jest",
      "^.+\\.js$": "babel-jest"
    },
    "setupFilesAfterEnv": ["<rootDir>/setupTests.ts"],
    "moduleFileExtensions": ["js", "ts", "svelte"]
  }
```

babel.config.js

```js
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      {
        targets: {
          node: "current"
        }
      }
    ]
  ]
};
```

svelte.config.cjs

```js
const sveltePreprocess = require('svelte-preprocess')

module.exports = {
  emitCss: true,
  preprocess: sveltePreprocess()
};
```

Among other things I tried to use `@babel/plugin-syntax-import-meta` but ended up with the same error. Also [vite-jest](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vite-jest) looked very promising but again I couldn't make it work.

I appreciate every hint I can get. If I can provide any additional info please let me know. Also my knowledge of vite and babel is very limited so REALLY appreciate any help IU can get on this topic.

**Update (Solution)**

So If you use babel you could use [babel-preset-vite](https://github.com/OpenSourceRaidGuild/babel-vite). The approach with `esbuild-jest` from Apu is also good solution that many people use. Unfortunately those things didn't work for me so I decided to use a workaround with vite's [define](https://vitejs.dev/config/#define).

This workaround consists of two steps.

1. replace `import.meta.env` with `process.env` (if this is a deal breaker for you then I hope you have luck with the solutions above) You only have to replace the instances in files you want to test with jest.
2. Update Vite config with define. This step is necessary or your build will break (dev will still work)

vite.config.js

```js
const dotEnvConfig = dotenv.config();

export default defineConfig({
  define: {
    "process.env.NODE_ENV": `"${process.env.NODE_ENV}"`,
    "process.env.VITE_APP_SOMENAME": `"${process.env.VITE_APP_SOMENAME}"`
  },
  ...
)};
```

I know this is just a workaround but maybe this helps someone. Thanks & Good Luck.

Answer (score 1):

A more recent alternative to Jest that understands `import.meta.env` is [Vitest](https://vitest.dev/).

It should require almost no additional configuration to get started and it's highly compatible with Jest so it requires few changes to the actual tests.

The advantages of Vitest over Jest for this use case are:

- It's designed specifically for Vite and will process tests on demand
- It will reuse your existing Vite configuration:

  - Any `define` variables will be replaced as expected
  - Extensions that Vite adds to `import.meta` will be available as usual

Answer (score -1):

I was having issues with svelte component testing as well using jest. babel is not good at resolving `import.meta`. I used `esbuild-jest` to transform both ts and js files. It solves the issue with the `import.meta`. Here is my jest.config.cjs.

`npm i esbuild esbuild-jest -D`

```
const { pathsToModuleNameMapper } = require('ts-jest/utils');
const { compilerOptions } = require('./tsconfig');

const config = {
  "transform": {
    "^.+\\.svelte$": [
      "svelte-jester",
      {
        "preprocess": true
      }
    ],
    "^.+\\.(ts|tsx|js|jsx)$":  ["esbuild-jest"]
  },
  "moduleFileExtensions": [
    "js",
    "ts",
    "tsx",
    "svelte"
  ],
  "setupFilesAfterEnv": [
    "@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect"
  ],
  "collectCoverageFrom": [
    "**/*.(t|j)s",
    "**/*.svelte"
  ],
  coverageProvider: 'v8',
  "coverageDirectory": "./coverage",
  "coveragePathIgnorePatterns": [
    "/node_modules/",
    "/.svelte-kit/"
  ],
  "moduleNameMapper": pathsToModuleNameMapper(compilerOptions.paths, {prefix: '<rootDir>/'})
};
  
  
module.exports = config;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, unfortunately this is not working either (same error). I'll keep trying and update my post if I find a solution

Comment: @Apfelbox! Thank you for your solution. I like your babel-preset-vite. It reduces other hassles that I was experiencing with import.meta not being available while running jest in the SSR env.

Comment: @Apfelbox how did you solve this problem ? I am facing the same problem